# java.lang.IllegalStateException: aliases expected length is 0; actual length is 1 when caching createSQLQuery

Tags: hibernate, caching

I am executing below code

```
SQLQuery query =  objectSession.createSQLQuery(queryString);
            query.setCacheable(true);
            query.setCacheRegion("My Space");
```

The queryString is a kind of UDF select statement and it just returns a string and that should be cached.

This returns below error message

java.lang.IllegalStateException: aliases expected length is 0; actual length is 1

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: What's your query looks like? Which db are you using and which Hibernate ORM version?

Comment: Select myfunc('abc', 'person','india') from sysibm.sysdummy1.using DB2 and hibernate version 4.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Try using a more recent Hibernate version. Hibernate 4 is not supported anymore.